# Instant resume for Windows 8.1?

Tags: gratis, windows-8

I was wondering but is there a program I can use so that when I close my Lenovo Red Laptop which runs Windows 8.1 (upgraded from Windows 7) to stay active when I close it. For example when I close my laptop lid and I am playing music, it still plays?

Note: There was something like this on my Lenovo Red Laptop but when I upgraded to 8.1 pro, it wiped all my applications including the built in ones from Lenovo such as Power Manager (not that I needed it though), also I cannot take it in at the moment since the person in charge of situations like this is away currently.

Any suggestions for a program that can fit my needs? Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is builtin in Windows 8 (and most likely windows 7 as well).

Open the Control Panel, search for "energy" and choose "edit the action on closing the lid". Here you have the option to change the action to "do nothing".

Comment: in case the exact wording is different, I had to translate it. Feel free to edit if it is named a little different :)

Comment: In Windows 7 it's called "Change what closing the lid does"